# Adding a field to a struct in Phoenix / Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to add a field or key to a struct which I return from an action:

```
def show(conn, _) do
   my_struct = Repo.get(MyStruc, 123)
   render(conn, my_item: Map.put(my_struct, :aaa, "fdsfdsfds"))
end
```

I need that field only in "show". 
An error:

```
key :aaa not found in: MyStruc {__meta__: ..........
```

I can return it as a separate value, but I want to return it embedded in MyStruct.

Comment: You have error with `my_item: item: Map.put...`. You can only use keys as atoms this way `key: :value`, not any other combination. Is it a bug only on SO?

Comment: What code is throwing that error? It can't be the code currently in the question.

Comment: @Dogbert, yes, it does.

Comment: @Dogbert, not anymore.

Comment: @Torito it must have been some code in the template. Can you post the complete error message including the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

```
defmodule MyStruct do
  use Ecto.Schema
  schema "my_struct" do
    ... all your fiels
    field :aaa, :string, virtual: true
  end
end
```

then in your code

```
def show(conn, _) do
  my_struct = Repo.get(MyStruc, 123)
  render(conn, my_item: %MyStruct{my_struct | aaa: "fdsfdsfds"})
end
```